# Setting the maximum number of button to be pressed

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code that allows me to display the number of models I have in my database. Each model details are tagged with a href button for the user to select.

1) Once the user clicked on the href button, the button's text will be changed to "selected".

2) If the user clicked on the button showing "selected", the button's text will be changed to "select".

```
<div class="row text-center">
    <?php
        while($rowModelList=mysql_fetch_array($resultModelList))
        {
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 hero-feature">
         <div class="thumbnail">
             <img src="Images/Models/<? echo $rowModelList['modelImage'];?>" alt="" style="height: 200px;">
             <div class="caption">
                 <h4><?php echo $rowModelList['modelName']?></h4>
                 <p>
                     <a href="#" id="<?php echo $rowModelList['modelName']?>" onClick="return changecolor(this)" class="btn btn-primary">Select</a>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

I have the following code that allows me to change the colour and text of the href button when clicked.

```
/* Changing the colour of the href button upon clicked */
function changecolor(element) {
  alert(element.target.id);
  if (element.innerHTML == "Select") {
    element.innerHTML = "Selected";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0"; /*Grey*/
    element.style.borderColor = "#C0C0C0";
    alert(element);
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = "Select";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#FED136"; /*Yellow*/
    element.style.borderColor = "#FED136";
    alert(element);
  }
  return false;
}
```

However, I am trying to restrict the number of buttons to be selected by the user.

For example, a list of 20 models is shown to the user but they are only allowed to select 8 of the model. Once 8 of the button's text are shown to be "selected", they will need to deselect one of the selected button in order to make new selection.

Any idea how I can modify the code to achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

simply count selected options in your function:

```
var selectedCount = 0; // global variable
function changecolor(element) {
  alert(element.target.id);
  if(selectedCount > 8)
  {
      alert("already selected 8 options");
      return false;
  }

  if (element.innerHTML == "Select") {
    element.innerHTML = "Selected";
    selected++;
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0"; /*Grey*/
    element.style.borderColor = "#C0C0C0";
    alert(element);
  } else {
    element.innerHTML = "Select";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#FED136"; /*Yellow*/
    element.style.borderColor = "#FED136";
    selected--;
    alert(element);
  }
  return false;
}
```

But its a lot easier if you use class for each element. Less code, and more control. Add class "selected" if element is checked, and remove it if unchecked. You dont need to style it in your javascript code.

jQuery example with class usage:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.option').click(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).hasClass('selected'))
        {
            // mark as unchecked
            jQuery(this).html('not selected');
            jQuery(this).removeClass('selected');
        }
        else
        {
            // mark as checked
            if(jQuery('.selected').length >= 2) // check limit
            {
                alert('to many selected');
                return false
            }
            jQuery(this).html('selected');
            jQuery(this).addClass('selected');
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable that tracks how many are selected

```
/* Changing the colour of the href button upon clicked */
var selectedCount = 0;
function changecolor(element) {
  if (selectedCount >=8 ) {
      return;
  }
  if (element.innerHTML == "Select") {
    selectedCount++;
    element.innerHTML = "Selected";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0"; /*Grey*/
    element.style.borderColor = "#C0C0C0";
    alert(element);
  } else {
    selectedCount--;
    element.innerHTML = "Select";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#FED136"; /*Yellow*/
    element.style.borderColor = "#FED136";
    alert(element);
  }
  return false;
}
```

You should avoid a global variable and you can do so using a closure/module pattern.

```
/* Changing the colour of the href button upon clicked */
var changecolor = (function(){
  var selectedCount = 0;
  function(element) {
    if (selectedCount >=8 ) {
      return;
    }
    if (element.innerHTML == "Select") {
      selectedCount++;
      element.innerHTML = "Selected";
      element.style.backgroundColor = "#C0C0C0"; /*Grey*/
      element.style.borderColor = "#C0C0C0";
      alert(element);
    } else {
      selectedCount--;
      element.innerHTML = "Select";
      element.style.backgroundColor = "#FED136"; /*Yellow*/
      element.style.borderColor = "#FED136";
      alert(element);
    }
    return false;
  }
})();
```